# Which Google API is used to find the distance between two points?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I want to find the distance between two cities say 'Mumbai' and 'Pune'.so which Google API (to be more specific, which function from which API) I can use which will accepts two parameters as input and returns the distance between them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: if you're wanting Driving Directions, here's how to do it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

You can just use the strings for Mumbai and Pune, you don't have to convert them to LatLng objects first (although that can still be done).

---

If you meant the distance as a straight line then you would need to convert 'Mumbai' and 'Pune' to latitude and longitudes.  For that you need to use the [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Once you have those, you can use the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) to calculate that distance.

Comment: Its driving distance, and not the straight path. still i can go in the way u have discribed, right?